# Calendar swiftUI with events

Tags: swift, date, events, calendar, swiftui

Is there a way to create a custom calendar where you can add events and all that things inside a swiftUI app? I have searched but all I can find is custom date pickers. Or is there a way to implement it from swift ? 
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/yodagamaheshan/DateGrid

Comment: You can customise it as you want